# How can I implement a factory to return a type that implements a generic interface, without knowing the generic type ahead of time?

Tags: c#, generics, factory

I have a situation in which I would like to instantiate a type that implements a generic interface, depending on the value of an `enum` passed to a factory method.  However, I'm having problems with the return type of the factory method.  I've created a short, complete program below which demonstrates what I'm trying to do:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace CreateGenericTypeFactory
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var request = new Request { RequestType = RequestType.A };
            var processor = ProcessorFactory.Create(request.RequestType);
            var result = processor.Process();
        }
    }

    public class ProcessorFactory
    {
        // This obviously doesn't work, as I don't know the
        // result type upfront.
        public static IRequestProcessor<TResult> Create<TResult>(RequestType requestType)
        {
            switch (requestType)
            {
                case RequestType.A:
                    return new RequestProcessorA();
                case RequestType.B:
                    return new RequestProcessorB();
                default:
                    throw new InvalidOperationException();
            }
        }
    }

    public interface IRequestProcessor<TResult>
    {
        TResult Process();
    }

    public class RequestProcessorA : IRequestProcessor<ResultA>
    {
        public ResultA Process() { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
    }
    public class RequestProcessorB : IRequestProcessor<ResultB>
    {
        public ResultB Process() { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
    }

    public class ResultA { }
    public class ResultB { }

    public enum RequestType { A, B }

    public class Request
    {
        public RequestType RequestType { get; set; }
        // Other properties
    }
}
```

As you can see, the implementations of `IRequestProcessor<TResult>` differ only by the type of result `Process()` returns.  In reality, those results are quite different, but the overall steps to both process, and return, the data should ideally be the same.

I contemplated the idea of mapping the enum values to the result types in a dictionary, then using that map to select, and construct, a result type, passing that to the factory instead, as it would then be able to infer the type, but I was wondering if there was a cleaner way.

Can any of you shed some light on a potential solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First Option**

You can change the declaration of `TResult` in `IRequestProcessor` as covariant. If you do so you've the ability to return a derived type as base type.

This will look like that:

```
public interface IRequestProcessor<out TResult>
{
    TResult Process();
}
```

The `out` declaration of `TRequest` is the key.

Having this you need a base type that ALL result types derive. I created a marker interface and all results implement it:

```
public interface IResult { }

public class ResultA : IResult { }
public class ResultB : IResult { }
```

Now you're able to handle all results as `IResult`. You could change the signature of `ProcessorFactory.Create`:

```
public static IRequestProcessor<IResult> Create(RequestType requestType)
{
    switch (requestType)
    {
        case RequestType.A:
            return new RequestProcessorA();
        case RequestType.B:
            return new RequestProcessorB();
        default:
            throw new InvalidOperationException();
    }
}
```

Now your code in `Main()` will compile and run as expected except the fact that you receive `IResult` instead of the special type.

That's the best you can do to handle all the common stuff. When it comes to the special cases you've to cast the result instance to the special type. You can't use generics to do that.

**Second option**

Another way meight be to create a generic method that contains the code of your `Main()` that knows the special type as generic parameter. In that case you can change the signature of `ProcessorFactory.Create` to the following and you've to cast all return values:

```
public static IRequestProcessor<TResult> Create<TResult>(RequestType requestType)
{
    switch (requestType)
    {
        case RequestType.A:
            return (IRequestProcessor<TResult>)new RequestProcessorA();
        case RequestType.B:
            return (IRequestProcessor<TResult>)new RequestProcessorB();
        default:
            throw new InvalidOperationException();
    }
}
```

You don't need the marker interface of first option in that case.

The cast will work because you create the correct request processor.
This returns correctly casted code but you need to move your `Main`-Code to a generic method or you specify the generic directly which makes `RequestType` obsolete.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  I considered the marker interface, but it just pushes the problem further down the line.  Effectively, I was hoping to be able to grab the type of result from the processor directly, and do what I wanted with it there.  Having read your answer now, it's clear to me that I need another level of abstraction between my service which creates the processors, and the processors themselves.  That way I should be able to accomplish what I want to do.  That said, your answer was very helpful, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

if we take your line of code that calls the process function and not use the `var` and try to solve it the will have a problem.

```
(ResultA|ResultB) result = processor.Process();
```

witch one will it be.. if we cant solve it.. we cant expect the compiler to solve it for us.. so.. what solutions we have..

1. Hard coded one

Split the definitions into separate (compatible) types, this is the worst as it will make you double the code and have `switch`es all over the place.

```
ResultA resultA = processorA.ProcessA();
ResultB resultB = processorB.ProcessB();
```

2. Remove ambiguity

Make your processor class return always the same type, unifying the return type with an interface, and removing the generics

```
public interface IResult { }
public class ResultA : IResult { }
public class ResultB : IResult { }

public interface IRequestProcessor //no longer needs generic
{
    IResult Process();
}
IResult result = processor.Process();
```

3. Go basic

if you really need the generics, and|or cant unify the code with interfaces.. just go the only thing you can count on.. everything is an object.. and ignore types whenever you have a conflict..

```
Object result = processor.Process();
```

personally I would go with solution 2.. single interfaces, because.. it's for this kind of situations they exist..

PS: Try to stop using `var`, is may be easier to write, but is harder to think ;)

Comment: `(ResultA|ResultB) result = processor.Process();` You're right that this is the core of the problem.  I agree with the first portion of your answer, and it was helpful in the sense that this was nagging at me, but you highlighting the same thing made me think about it some more. Regarding your last comment, I used `var` only to convey my intention, nothing more.  See my reply to @Vera rind's answer as to what I think the real solution is.